# What kind of toad is this 2.5 inch (6.5cm) one yellow with brown spots and a white back stripe?

Tags: animal-identification, colorado

I just found this toad on a sidewalk near a lake the elevation was probably somewhere around 4800 ft (1500m).

[image]

Does anybody know what kind it is?

Comment: Lick it and find out!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note: This answer has been revised based on a higher quality photo**

I am not a toad expert, but I think it is likely a [Woodhouse's Toad](https://gonefroggin.com/2019/01/15/woodhouses-toad-anaxyrus-woodhousii/) based on [this handy guide](https://cpw.state.co.us/Documents/Education/StudentActivities/COHerpQuickKey.pdf).  One of the key features is the pale stripe down the back and the cranial crests; the absence of which would make it a [Boreal Toad](https://gonefroggin.com/2019/02/26/western-toad-anaxyrus-boreas/) or the large symmetrical dark splotches that would make it a [Great Plains Toad](https://www.birdandhike.com/Wildlife/Amphib/Bufo_cog/_Buf_cog.htm).

This is a cropped photo from the question showing the cranial crests circled.
[image: Photo from OP with cranial crests circle (correctly this time, I hope)]

One other note is that it is more likely to be found below 7,000 feet of elevation, unlike a Boreal Toad which is usually found above 8,000 feet.

You can see a picture of a Woodhouse's Toad here:

[image: Photo of a Woodhouse's Toad]

I originally came to the conclusion that it was a boreal toad based on the original photo using [this site](https://gonefroggin.com/2016/09/26/frogs-toads-colorado/), but I wanted to use a more step-by-step method, so I followed the guide that I mentioned [earlier](https://cpw.state.co.us/Documents/Education/StudentActivities/COHerpQuickKey.pdf).  Given the update photo, the aforementioned guide would suggest that it is instead a Woodhouse's Toad. I am including the relevant page of the guide as an image (original is a pdf) to guard against link rot.

Your toad has warty skin, a light stripe, no large blotches, and large cranial crests, as best as I can tell, which implies that it is a Woodhouse's Toad.

[image: Quick guide to frogs and toads of Colorado, pdf link here: https://cpw.state.co.us/Documents/Education/StudentActivities/COHerpQuickKey.pdf]

Comment: I added a much better  picture, first one was on my phone and the upload limit was causing problems

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh I may actually reverse my guess based on that.  I think I can see the cranial crests that would suggest a Woodhouse's Toad.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh upon further thought, I am fairly sure that my revised answer is now correct.  The updated photo did wonders in regards to identification.

Comment: I think your right, but that you have the cranial crest circled incorrectly  and instead circled the parotoid glands https://www.google.com/search?q=toad+cranial+crest&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS810US810&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4icm79_HiAhUGA6wKHbqRBlAQ_AUIECgB&biw=1920&bih=969#imgrc=EuCL3Rhx831zMM:

Comment: You've got me there, @CharlieBrumbaugh .  I'll correct that.  Thanks for pointing that out.